# FQL get status updates from stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, stream, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying you get the status updates from stream table, I am using php sdk and in my query is specify type to be 45 (which is status update type) but it is not working and I get no results, below is my code for the query:

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. 'fql?q=SELECT+description+FROM+stream+WHERE+type=45+LIMIT+1000'
. '&access_token=' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

Can somebody help me? What is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The status update type is 46. Also, you need a column in your where clause that is indexable. That is done by accessing all the things visible by you:

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE
filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed')
AND type=46 LIMIT 1000
```